# How use data from store in fetch action (react-redux)

Tags: redux, fetch

How can I made fetch chain async actions where second fetch is using data from first? I need fetch repository list (GitHub API) and then fetch users from those repos. I made this:

```js
export function reposListFetchData(url) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(reposListIsLoading(true))

    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if(!response.ok){
          throw Error(response.statusText)
        }

        dispatch(reposListIsLoading(false))

        return response
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((repos) => dispatch(reposListFetchSuccess(repos)))
      .then( this.props.repos.map(
  repo=>this.props.fetchContributorsData(`https://api.github.com/repos/angular/${repo.name}/contributors?per_page=100`)
      ))
     .catch(()=> dispatch(reposListHasErrored(true)))
   }
}
```

but of course I cant use `this.props` there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `fetchContributorsData` is an action that is quite similar with the `reposListFetchData`, you should be able to do this...

```
export function reposListFetchData(url) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(reposListIsLoading(true));
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        dispatch(reposListIsLoading(false));
        return response;
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(repos => {
        dispatch(reposListFetchSuccess(repos));
        // where repos is an array of repo
        repos.map(repo =>
          dispatch(fetchContributorsData(`https://api.github.com/repos/angular/${repo.name}/contributors?per_page=100`))
        );
      })
      .catch(() => dispatch(reposListHasErrored(true)));
  };
}
```